# show this induces a metric.

Tags: solution-verification, metric-spaces

Let $p$ be an odd prime integer and define a metric $d: \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as follows

$$d(m,n)=0 \space \text{if $n=m$}$$

and

$$d(m,n)=\frac{1}{r+1} \space \text{if $n \neq m$}$$

where $r \in \mathbb{Z}^{\geq 0}$ such that

$$p^r \vert \vert m-n$$.

($p^r \vert \vert a \Rightarrow$ $r$ is the largest integer such that $p^r \vert a$ but $p^{r+1} \nmid a$.)

Show $d$ is metric on $\mathbb{Z}$:

For symmetry, does it follow $d(m,n)=d(n-m)$

because

$$p^r \vert \vert m-n \Rightarrow p^r \vert \vert n-m$$

and positivity since $r \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, $d(m,n)\geq 0$ with equality holding iff $m=n$.

I haven't worked out triangle inequality, but so far am I on the right track?

For triangle inequality do I need to introduce $q,s$ for the distance between $(m,l)$ and $(l,n)$?

So do I let $r$ be the integer such that $p^r \vert \vert m-n$, $q$ be the integer such that $p^q \vert \vert m - l$ and $s$ be the integer such that $p^s \vert \vert l-n$ and show

$$\frac{1}{r+1}\leq \frac{1}{q+1}+\frac{1}{s+1}$$

?? Any help?? Since I want to show $d(m,n) \leq d(m,l)+d(l,n)$

Comment: The equality part seems to be obvious since you've defined a metric which cannot be zero unless $m=n$. I don't know what $\mid\mid$ is so I don't know about the symmetry part.

Comment: $p^r \vert \vert a$ means $r$ is the largest positive integer such that $p^r \vert a$ @SuzuHirose

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I'm not sure what "latest" means in your comment.

Comment: means largest @SuzuHirose

Comment: @SuzuHirose could you check if my triangle inequality on the right path ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have done everything else, it remains to verify the triangle inequality. We want to show $d(m,n) \leq d(m,l)+d(l,n)$. We may assume that all $m,k,n$ are different as otherwise the inequality is trivial. With $r,q,s$ as in your post we note that $r\geq \min(q,s)$ and therefore $$\frac{1}{r+1}\leq \frac{1}{\min(q,s)+1}\leq\frac{1}{q+1} + \frac{1}{s+1}, $$ as desired.

Comment: why is $r \geq \min\{q,s\}$?

Comment: is it because $p^r \vert \vert m-n$ $\Rightarrow$ $p^r \vert \vert (m-l)+(l-n)$

Comment: We use that $m-n = (m-l)+(l-n)$ so $p^q \mid m-l$ and $p^s \mid l-n$ implies $p^{\min(q,s)} \mid (m-l) + (l-n) = m-n$.

Comment: and and since $p^r \vert \vert m-n$ we conclude $r \geq \min\{q,s\}$? Thanks!!!!

Comment: with respect to this metric, I need to show if the set of even numbers is closed or not. Do I use the fact that the difference of even numbers need be even?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do it, and some variation of what you suggest should work, but it seems like the topic for another question.

Answer (score 1):

For the $\triangle$ inequality it suffices that $d(\ell,n)\le d(\ell,m)+d(m,n)$ when $\ell\ne m$ and $m\ne n.$

Let $m=\ell +Ap^r$ where $ A\in\Bbb Z$ and $p\not |A.$ Let $n=m+Bp^s$ where $B\in\Bbb Z$ and $p\not |B.$ (With $r,s\in\Bbb N_0$.) Then $n=\ell +Ap^r+Bp^s.$  So $p^{\min (r,s)}|(n-\ell).$ Therefore $$d(\ell,n)\le \frac {1}{\min \{r+1,s+1
\}}=$$ $$= \max \{\frac {1}{r+1},\frac {1}{s+1}
\}$$ $$<\frac {1}{r+1}+\frac {1}{s+1}=$$ $$=d(\ell,m)+d(m,n).$$

Comment: There is a name for the kind of metric where $d(x,z)\le \max \{d(x,y),d(y,z)\}$ but I forgot it.

Comment: An Ultrametric?

Comment: @BrandonduPreez .Yes. That is the name!